# Using a code snippet multiple times in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that I've a String variable strTemp5. I just want to give it a value once in my public sub and then use it in 33 normal subs. But it appears that I've to define it everytime right now. Is there any way I can use the same String by only defining it once.

Comment: Declare it as a `PUBLIC` variable in a module. [INTERESTING READ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If it's only ever the same value.

```
Public Const <variable> as <type> = x
```

Example.

```
Public Const numberofbats as Long = 6
```